# Where did I mistake?

Tags: pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="1bln", overlay = true, initial_capital = 1000)

src = close
lenrsi = input(3, "RSI Length")
lenupdown = input(1, "UpDown Length")
lenroc = input(100, "ROC Length")
updown(s) =>
    isEqual = s == s[1]
    isGrowing = s > s[1]
    ud = 0.0
    ud := isEqual ? 0 : isGrowing ? (nz(ud[1]) <= 0 ? 1 : nz(ud[1])+1) : (nz(ud[1]) >= 0 ? -1 : nz(ud[1])-1)
rsi = ta.rsi(src, lenrsi)
updownrsi = ta.rsi(updown(src), lenupdown)
percentrank = ta.percentrank(ta.roc(src, 1), lenroc)
crsi = math.avg(rsi, updownrsi, percentrank) // Connors rsi

if crsi > 70
    strategy.close_all()

var first_entry_time = strategy.opentrades.entry_time(0)
var second_entry_time = strategy.opentrades.entry_time(1)
var make_first_entry = first_entry_time + 5 * 60 * 1000 // time out first take
var make_second_entry = second_entry_time + 10 * 60 * 1000 // time out second take
var initial_entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
var second_entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1)
lowestLow = ta.lowest(low, 100)
var initial_price_decrease = initial_entry_price - initial_entry_price * 0.005
var second_price_decrease = second_entry_price - second_entry_price * 0.008

if(crsi == 15 and make_second_entry == time and second_price_decrease <= lowestLow)
    strategy.entry("take_3", strategy.long, limit = strategy.initial_capital * 0.25) 
else if(crsi < 20 and make_first_entry == time and initial_price_decrease <= lowestLow)
    strategy.entry("take_2", strategy.long, limit = strategy.initial_capital * 0.2) 
else
    strategy.entry("take_1", strategy.long, limit = strategy.initial_capital * 0.15)
```

I wrote a strategy that should buy to the indicator CRSI, the strategy pauses between purchases. And checks the price difference between inputs.
I cant understand why it doesnt work?

I removed parts of the code, but the second and third purchases dont work.

Comment: I wonder how the title was accepted..

Comment: I didnt know what to title it

Answer (score 0):

1. You use `var` declaration of variables, and you don't redefine their value anywhere, so they will keep their state from the moment of the first call. Maybe I misunderstood your logic and you want to write code for just a few trades just for testing, but I will assume that you did it by accident (better to warn when not needed than to guess)
2. You use `strategy.opentrades.entry_time(1)` without `pyramiding` enabled, in which case this call will always be `na`, since at no point in time can you have two open trades at the same time. If you want to open more than one trade before closing the current one, redefine the value of the `pyramiding` argument of the `strategy()` function
3. Follows from 1 and 2. Calling `strategy.opentrades.entry_time()` before opening a trade returns `na`, your logic is based on checking the time from this function, with boolean expressions with `na` the result is always `false`. Since you declare variables in which you write the result of this function calculation as `var` and do not redefine its value anywhere, your conditions using these variables will always be `false`.